# Android 7 inch tablet values folder

Tags: android, android-resources

I have checked my layout an looks correctly, except 1 device landscape mode, which I would like to fix it.

[Supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) looks outdated.

600dp: a **7”** tablet (**600x1024** mdpi).

720dp: a **10”** tablet (720x1280 mdpi, **800x1280** **mdpi**, etc).

**mdpi** Resources for medium-density (mdpi) screens (~**160dpi**). (This is the baseline density.)

**hdpi** Resources for high-density (hdpi) screens (~**240dpi**).

My device is a 7" tablet with 800 x 1280 resolution: [SM T235](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_tab_4_7_0_lte-6241.php) has 216 dpi

I am wondering how could I fix his layout dimensions in landscape mode with less impact to others.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/top_left" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:text="Tel: "
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="123456789" />


</LinearLayout>
```

The imageView should be closer to left margin and the TextView with "Tel:" should be closer to image. But only in landscape mode and at this device.
I have other device to test: 10" same resolution , and should not affect that.

I think the `@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin` needs to be changed in `/res/values/dimens.xml` by adding some suffixes to `values` folder.
I have generated the `values-v21` and `values-w820dp`

**EDIT:**
The generated file at android Studio: res/**values-w820dp**/dimens.xml

```
<resources>
    <!-- Example customization of dimensions originally defined in res/values/dimens.xml
         (such as screen margins) for screens with more than 820dp of available width. This
         would include 7" and 10" devices in landscape (~960dp and ~1280dp respectively). -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">64dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

I have no idea why takes values from **values-w820dp** since my width is less than 820. I just needed to append the **-land**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have overlooked **`tvdpi`** qualifier of [the page](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers).

So you can use a specific dimens.xml as:

```
/res/values-land-tvdpi/dimens.xml
```

**EDIT**

When you use multiple qualifiers, order of these qualifiers should be the one of in the [table2](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#table2). See: [Qualifier Rules](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#QualifierRules).

Comment: Never used tvdpi, it seems I should start to use, even for tablets and not TV :)

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':AndroidApp:mergeDebugResources'.
> ...AndroidApp\src\main\res\values-tvdpi-land: Error: Invalid resource directory name

Comment: I don't know why, but this is the solution: values-w820dp-land

Comment: That is because `w820dp` is before the `land` qualifier in the table2. I think `values-land-tvdpi` will be also ok, won't it?